# Es lo mismo ul > li que hacer simplemente ul li?

Tags: css, scss

Me tiene un poco confundido , estuve en freecodecamp practicando un poco de lo que es css, y al comienzo utilizaba ul li, por ejemplo,pero en otras ocasiones mas adelante me decia que utilizara ul > li.Hay alguna diferencia entre estos?

Comment: Si, si son [diferentes](https://cybmeta.com/el-selector-css-o-mayor-que). Ahora te invito a que mires [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues si, en tu ejemplo realiza el mismo proceso, afectar todos las etiquetas

dentro de . Pero si tienen cierta diferencia...

Veras, el espacio (ul li) afectara todos los elementos li dentro de ul
Mientras que
el sign (ul > li) afectara todos los elementos li que sean hijos DIRECTOS de ul

Es decir, si agregases un div con elementos li dentro, solo serian afectados mediante la primera forma (ul li), no por la segunda ya que, como mencione, solo afectara a los hijos directos y los li dentro del div no entraria en esa categoria

Answer (score 0):

`ul li` afectará a los `li` de listas ordenadas ( `ol li` ) cuando se encuentren dentro de una lista desordenada ( `ul li ol li` ).

`ul > li` afectará a los `li` sólo si estan dentro de una lista desordenada

```css
li {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: normal
}

ul li {
  font-weight: bold
}

ul>li {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>lista lvl1</li>
  <li>lista lvl1
    <ul>
      <li>lista lvl2</li>
      <li>lista lvl2</li>
      <li>lista lvl2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>lista o lvl2</li>
      <li>lista o lvl2</li>
      <li>lista o lvl2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>lista lvl1</li>
</ul>
```